# Linear programming with a second decision variable in the constraint vector

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, optimization, linear-programming, optimal-transport

Is the following optimization problem feasible (modified optimal transport)? The primary decision variable appears in the objective function as $\mathbf{x}$,  whereas the second decision variable $\mathbf{y}\in \mathbb{R}^K$ is introduced in the constraint vector $\mathbf{b}$: This variable will be optimized as an optimal weight vector for multiplication against a multivariate data matrix $\mathbf{M}\in \mathbb{R}^{N\times K}$ as shown in the last bullet point. Product $\mathbf{M} \cdot \mathbf{y}$ therefore is an optimally weighted version of the original matrix, or optimal source distribution, but of size $N\times 1$.

$$
\begin{array}{rrcl}
\arg \min_{\mathbf{x}, \, \mathbf{y}} \ & \mathbf{c}^\top \mathbf{x} &  & \ \\
\mathrm{s.t.} \ & \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x} & = & \ \mathbf{b} \\
 \  & \mathbf{x} & \geq &\ \mathbf{0}
\end{array}$$

- $\mathbf{c}$ is a vectorization of the distance matrix $\boldsymbol C$,
- $\mathbf{x}$ is a vectorization of the transport matrix  $\boldsymbol\Gamma$,
- while the source and target distributions are $\mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} \mathbf{M} \cdot \mathbf{y}\\ \beta\end{bmatrix}$

Any comments on this optimization set-up with two decision variables would be helpful.

*(Next issue is how to make standard solvers like `scipy.optimize.linprog` admit the existence of a second decision variable, because the documentation of most solvers only addresses one decision variable only. but [I ask this part at stack instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65097511/how-to-introduce-a-second-decision-variable-array-into-python-linear-programmi))*

Comment: could you elaborate the optimization problem itself a bit more (in words)?

Comment: You just treat the long vector $(x,y)$ as one decision variable. The distinction into $x$ and $y$ parts is just for your notational convenience, the solver does not care. Also the phrase "decision variable in constraint vector" is just confusing oneself. It is just another bunch of ordinary linear constraints.

Comment: How do I treat the combined vector $(x,y)$ as one decision variable exactly, especially when $x$ appears in the objective fn and $y$ appears in the constraint? and can you lead me to examples where the decision variable appears in the constraint, rather than the objective function? I've never seen that before

Comment: @Steven01123581321 the intuition and how it carries over to linear programming can be found here: https://vincentherrmann.github.io/blog/wasserstein/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your objective function can be written as $c^T x + 0^T y$.
Your constraints can be written in block-matrix form with constant RHS as follows, where the subscripts indicate the sizes:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
A'_{\ell \times n}  & -M_{\ell \times K}\\
A''_{\ell \times n} & 0_{\ell \times K}\\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
x_{n \times 1}\\
y_{K \times 1}\\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0_{\ell \times 1}\\
\beta_{\ell \times 1}\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If your solver requires a single vector of decision variables, then rename $y$, as described by @MichalAdamaszek.  Explicitly, $$(x_1,\dots,x_n,y_1,\dots,y_K)$$ becomes $$(x_1,\dots,x_n,x_{n+1},\dots,x_{n+K}).$$

Comment: makes a bit more sense than what I had in mind: $Ax = My$, since  I wasn't sure how to change the `b_eq` constraint vector ($b$) to the matrix product $My$. $\beta$ is a target distribution's histogram simplex. Now the issue is how to concatenate $My$ with $\beta$ to form vector $b$ ex ante, since I can't just throw $\beta$ away. $My$ is a matrix-vector product containing a decision variable, whereas $\beta$ is a given vector not dependent on $M$ nor $y$

Comment: What are the sizes of $A$, $b$, $c$, $x$, and $\beta$?

Comment: without confusing $n$ for $N$, the sizes are $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^m,  \mathbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^n,  \mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, where usually $m=n$ (histograms are same length), while $\beta$ is the lower half of $\mathbf{b}$. I've replaced the source histogram simplex $\alpha$ that appeared in the standard $\mathbf{b}$ with $M y$. More details on the arrays in the section called "Linear Programming" here: https://vincentherrmann.github.io/blog/wasserstein/

Comment: So $m=2\ell$, with $\beta\in \mathbb{R}^\ell$ and $M\in \mathbb{R}^{\ell \times K}$?

Comment: yeah I guess you could say that. but the tutorial also notes "This means $n = \ell^2$. For the constraints, we concatenate the target distributions, which makes $m=2\ell$"

Comment: what is the difference between $A'$ and $A''$ in the edit compared to $A$? and have you removed $0^\top y$ from the objective function only because it was zero anyways

Comment: $A=\begin{pmatrix} A' \\ A'' \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: currently there is a non-negativity constraint on $x$. I would still like to retain this, but If I rename the combined decision variables $x$ inclusive of $y$, how can I additionally impose a new constraint to only bound $y\in [-1,1]$?

Comment: You can use the bounds= option to impose bounds $[0, \infty]$ on the first $n$ variables and $[-1, 1]$ on the last $K$ variables.

Comment: If originally $$\boldsymbol{A} =
\begin{pmatrix}
1_n^\top \otimes \mathbb{I}_m \\  \mathbb{I}_n  \otimes  1_m^\top
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{(m+n)\times mn}$$ shouldn't $$A' = \begin{pmatrix}
1_n^\top \otimes \mathbb{I}_m
\end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times mn}?$$ you have the column shaped $n$ instead of $mn$ in yours. not sure which is right

Comment: by the way, $M_{\ell \times K}$ is actually shaped $M_{N \times K}$. We are interested in forming  the histogram simplex $\alpha$ *of* $\mathbf{M} \cdot \mathbf{y}$ that is the same shape as $\beta$, since $\mathbf{M} \cdot \mathbf{y}$, as is (being raw data rather than probabilities), is not the same shape as $\beta$. I know this part would be the toughest to include in the linear program but there must be a way, like an interior function of some sort